# Automating Exchange Mail Box Export using Task Scheduler and Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, scheduled-tasks, exchange-server

i'm trying to regularly export PST files from user mail boxes in MS Exchange v14.1 (build 218.15) as an alternative means of Backing up. I'm running on Windows SBS 2011.

I have a powershell script that looks like this...

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
. $env:ExchangeInstallPath\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1
Connect-ExchangeServer -auto

$lastweek = (get-date).AddDays(-7)
$date1 = $lastweek.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
$date2 = (get-date).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
$path = "\\master\PSTFiles\"+$date2+"\"
New-Item -Path $path -type directory | Out-Null

New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter "Received -gt'$date1'" -ExcludeFolders "#DeletedItems#" -Mailbox myusername -FilePath $path"myusername.pst"
```

I then call this script using Task Scheduler with a set up like this...

```
Start Program: C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Arguments: .\my-exchange-export-script.ps1
Start in: C:\BackupScript
```

which is set up to run using a domain user account, whether logged in or not and with Run with highest privileges set. This user account has domain administrator permissions on the Server and the Exchange "Import / Export" Role under RBAC.

Additionally i've also "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force" for this user account and in desperation i've also turned off UAC settings for the Server too.

The script runs fine if i just right click it and "run with Powershell", 
however when triggered by the Task Scheduler starts but only gets as far as creating the new directory, and then doesn't do anything else.

Has anyone any useful suggestions as to what might be stopping my request and what i could do to make it work?

Cheers
phil

Comment: You don't need to load that snapin.  Just connect to an Exchange session, and use Invoke-Command on your export request, pointed at that session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i've fixed it, but i'm not sure which of the many things i've tried did the job.

i've added the security permission "WSS_ADMIN_WGP" to the user account just because the Administrator role had it.

I've upgraded to Exchange 2010 SP3 and given my user account every Exchange role i could find.

I added an intermediate step in calling the script so now the SCHEDULED TASK looks like this...

```
Start Program: C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Arguments: .\run-as-admin-script.ps1
Start in: C:\BackupScript
```

Then "run-as-admin-script.ps1" looks like this (this requires UAC to be turned off
)

```
Start-Process "$psHome\powershell.exe" -verb runas -ArgumentList "-file C:\BackupScript\exchange-export-script-incremental.ps1"
```

And "exchange-export-script-incremental.ps1" now looks like this...

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
. $env:ExchangeInstallPath\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1
Connect-ExchangeServer -auto

$lastweek = (get-date).AddDays(-7)
$tomorrow = (get-date).AddDays(+1)
$date2 = (get-date).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
$path = "\\master\PSTFiles\"+$date2+"\"

New-Item -Path $path -type directory | Out-Null

New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {(Received -gt $lastweek) -and (Received -lt $tomorrow)} -Mailbox myusername -FilePath $path"myusername.pst"
```

And this runs successfully!

The chances are that some of the steps i've taken and permissions i've set are redundant for the task but i can't be bothered to eliminate them

Hope this is useful to someone else.